# How to validate and insert multiple record using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, multiple-records

I use Codeigniter.I have a table.

and this is of source code of view

```
<?php $this->load->view("admin/v_header");?>
<?php $this->load->view("admin/v_top_menu");?>
<?php $this->load->view("admin/v_sidebar");?>
<div class="content">
    <div class="header">
        <h1 class="page-title"><?php echo "Form Set Bobot Matapraktikum $kode_mp";?></h1>
    </div>
    <?php $this->load->view("admin/v_alert_msg");?>
    <form class="form-horizontal" name="set_bobot" action="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/save_set_bobot" method="POST">
        <fieldset>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Minggu Praktikum</th>
                        <th>Bobot TP</th>
                        <th>Bobot Jurnal</th>
                        <th>Bobot TA</th>
                        <th>Bobot Tubes</th>
                        <th>Bobot Mingguan</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>

                    <?php 

                    foreach($total_minggu_praktikum->result() as $row):
                        $total=$row->jumlah_minggu_praktikum;
                    for($i=1;$i<=$total;$i++)
                    {
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>".$i."</td>";
                        echo "<td><input type='number' min='0' max='100' name='bobot_tp".$i."' value='0' required='true' class='input-mini'/></td>";
                        echo "<td><input type='number' min='0' max='100' name='bobot_jurnal".$i."' value='0' required='true' class='input-mini'/></td>";
                        echo "<td><input type='number' min='0' max='100' name='bobot_ta".$i."' value ='0'required='true' class='input-mini'/></td>";
                        echo "<td><input type='number' min='0' max='100' name='bobot_tubes".$i."' value='0' required='true' class='input-mini'/></td>";
                        echo "<td><input type='number' min='0' name='bobot_mingguan".$i."' value='0' required='true' class='input-mini'/></td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                    }
                    ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="total" value="<?php echo $i-1;?>"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="kode_mp" value="<?php echo $kode_mp;?>"/>
                    <?php
                    endforeach;

                    ?>
                   </tbody>
               </table>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >
                        <i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i>Save
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
<?php $this->load->view("admin/v_footer");?>
```

and this is source code of controller

```
function save_set_bobot()
{
    $total=  $this->input->post('total');
    $kode_mp= $this->input->post('kode_mp');

    for($i=1;$i<=$total;$i++)
    {
        $bobot_tp[$i] =  $this->input->post("bobot_tp".$i);
        $bobot_jurnal[$i]=  $this->input->post("bobot_jurnal".$i);
        $bobot_ta[$i]=  $this->input->post("bobot_ta".$i);
        $bobot_tubes[$i]=  $this->input->post("bobot_tubes".$i);
        $bobot_mingguan[$i]=  $this->input->post("bobot_mingguan".$i);


        if($bobot_tp[$i]+$bobot_jurnal[$i]+$bobot_ta[$i]+$bobot_tubes[$i]!=100)
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("error_msg","Total jumlah bobot TP, Jurnal, TA dan Tubes pada minggu praktikum $i harus 100");
            redirect("admin/set_bobot2?matapraktikum=$kode_mp");
        }
        else
        {
            $prm['kode_mp']=$kode_mp;
            $prm['minggu_praktikum']=$i;
            $prm['bobot_tp']=$bobot_tp[$i];
            $prm['bobot_jurnal']=$bobot_jurnal[$i];
            $prm['bobot_ta']=$bobot_ta[$i];
            $prm['bobot_tubes']=$bobot_tubes[$i];
            $prm['bobot_mingguan']=$bobot_mingguan[$i];

            if($this->mbbt->save($prm))
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata("success_msg","Data bobot berhasil disimpan");
                redirect("admin/act_list_bobot?matapraktikum=$kode_mp");
            }
            else
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata("error_msg","Data bobot gagal disimpan");
            }
        }     
    }
}
```

before I want to insert this data into database, I must check the validation of this data,
where The sum of Bobot Tp, Bobot Jurnal, Bobot Ta and Bobot Tubes must 100 every of minggu praktium(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10). and The sum of column Bobot Mingguan must 100.
I can't validate of this rule. How I can to validate this?
and the validate of this rule must check every row of Minggu Praktikum (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) and check the sum of column Bobot Mingguan must be 100.
if this rule is true and I must insert the data only one action (using insert_batch).
I hope, You give me an Idea, how to solve this problem. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Please add **javascript** validation in your form may help you further.

If you want to redirect if one error exist use redirect other wise collect the errors and display it later.

Insert the values using insert batch in your model file.

**Note:** Please read the inline comments further.

```
function save_set_bobot()
{
    $total=  $this->input->post('total');
    $kode_mp= $this->input->post('kode_mp');

   $data = array();

   $error = array();

    for($i=1;$i<=$total;$i++)
    {
        $bobot_tp[$i] =  $this->input->post("bobot_tp".$i);
        $bobot_jurnal[$i]=  $this->input->post("bobot_jurnal".$i);
        $bobot_ta[$i]=  $this->input->post("bobot_ta".$i);
        $bobot_tubes[$i]=  $this->input->post("bobot_tubes".$i);
        $bobot_mingguan[$i]=  $this->input->post("bobot_mingguan".$i);


        if($bobot_tp[$i]+$bobot_jurnal[$i]+$bobot_ta[$i]+$bobot_tubes[$i]!=100)
        {
            //error exist please collect the details into the array           
            $error["bobot_error".$i"] = "Total jumlah bobot TP, Jurnal, TA dan Tubes pada minggu praktikum $i harus 100"

            //If you want to redirect if one error exist please redirect here other wise collect the errors and display it later
            //$this->session->set_flashdata("error_msg","Total jumlah bobot TP, Jurnal, TA dan Tubes pada minggu praktikum $i harus 100");
            //redirect("admin/set_bobot2?matapraktikum=$kode_mp");
        }
        else
        {
            $prm  = array();
            $prm['kode_mp']=$kode_mp;
            $prm['minggu_praktikum']=$i;
            $prm['bobot_tp']=$bobot_tp[$i];
            $prm['bobot_jurnal']=$bobot_jurnal[$i];
            $prm['bobot_ta']=$bobot_ta[$i];
            $prm['bobot_tubes']=$bobot_tubes[$i];
            $prm['bobot_mingguan']=$bobot_mingguan[$i];

            //other wise move the values into the $data array
            $data[] = $prm;
        }     
    }

    //insert the values using insert batch in your model file
    //$this->db->insert_batch('Table Name', $data);

    //if you want to redirect at the end use like this
    if(count($error)>0) 
    {
      $this->session->set_flashdata("error_msg","Total jumlah bobot TP, Jurnal, TA dan Tubes pada minggu praktikum $i harus 100");
      redirect("admin/set_bobot2?matapraktikum=$kode_mp");
    }
}
```

Comment: oh, I see, I must collect the errors and $prm in array. but what about column Bobot Mingguan? how I can to sum of this value of column? this value must 100 too. Thx